# Wireless adapter is installed but cannot be up using ifup

Tags: wireless, server, adapter

1. When i use the command lshw my wireless adapter properties is shown in detail.
2. I edited the file /etc/network/interfaces to enabling wifi adapter.
3. But, When i use ifup for enabling wifi adapter the system goes the system goes through an **Infinite Error Loop**!

what can  I do?

The contents of the /etc/network/interfaces is as follows:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp3s0 
iface wlp3s0 
inet static ipaddress 192.168.0.100 
network 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1 
wpa-ssid ***** 
wpa-psk ******
```

**Edit:**
This problem happened in UBUNTU Server 16.04. 
I also tried to install Mint 17.1 but even before the beginning of installation the same **Infinite Error Loop** happens which i think the reason is that because Mint uses wireless network through installation!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the /etc/network/interfaces file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you edit your file to:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp3s0 
iface wlp3s0 inet static 
address 192.168.0.100 
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1 
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
wpa-ssid ***** 
wpa-psk ******
```

Test:

```
sudo ifdown wlp3s0 && sudo ifup wlp3s0
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Post any errors.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is not resolved. I edited my question for more information.